Laplace spectrum on $U(n)$
Consider $\psi:SU(n)\times U(1)\to U(n)$, $(w,z)\mapsto \bar{z}\cdot w$. One can show that $\psi$ serves as a projection and $SU(n)\times U(1)$ is a principal $\mathbb Z_n$-bundle over $U(n)$.
Suppose we are given a bi-invariant metric $g$ on $SU(n)$ and the canonical metric $h = d\theta^2$ on $U(1)$. I want to show that the product metric $g\oplus h$ on $SU(n)\times U(1)$ induces a bi-invariant metric $G$ on $U(n)$ in such a way that $\psi$ is a local isometry. How do I do that?
Finally, given $f\in C^\infty(U(n))$ with $\Delta_{U(n)}f = \mu f$ for some $\mu>0$, how do I show that also $\Delta_{SU(n)\times U(1)}\psi^*f = \mu \psi^*f$?
